# Cannot create an Instance for a ListFragment class in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, instance, viewmodel

I am trying to create a getInstance function inside a companion object in a Fragment class called "ListFragment" which returns an instance of ListFragment. I am trying to get the instance of this fragment from a viewModel class which is being used in the same fragment. By doing this, I am getting following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment ListFragment{b13aa81} (7e6b48f5-7ae5-4b8b-b19f-13b3df28c66c) not attached to an activity.
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.requireActivity(Fragment.java:995)
        at in.machine_test.arun.viewmodels.ListFragmentViewModel.showToast(ListFragmentViewModel.kt:106)
        at in.machine_test.arun.viewmodels.ListFragmentViewModel$insert$1$2.emit(ListFragmentViewModel.kt:60)
        at in.machine_test.arun.viewmodels.ListFragmentViewModel$insert$1$2.emit(ListFragmentViewModel.kt:59)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__ErrorsKt$catchImpl$2.emit(Errors.kt:158)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.SafeCollectorKt$emitFun$1.invoke(SafeCollector.kt:15)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.SafeCollectorKt$emitFun$1.invoke(SafeCollector.kt:15)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.SafeCollector.emit(SafeCollector.kt:87)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.SafeCollector.emit(SafeCollector.kt:66)
        at in.machine_test.arun.data.repository.LocalRepository$insert$1.invokeSuspend(LocalRepository.kt:24)
        at in.machine_test.arun.data.repository.LocalRepository$insert$1.invoke(Unknown Source:8)
        at in.machine_test.arun.data.repository.LocalRepository$insert$1.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.SafeFlow.collectSafely(Builders.kt:61)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.AbstractFlow.collect(Flow.kt:230)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.ChannelFlowOperatorImpl.flowCollect(ChannelFlow.kt:195)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.ChannelFlowOperator.collect$suspendImpl(ChannelFlow.kt:167)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.ChannelFlowOperator.collect(Unknown Source:0)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__ErrorsKt.catchImpl(Errors.kt:156)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt.catchImpl(Unknown Source:1)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__ErrorsKt$catch$$inlined$unsafeFlow$1.collect(SafeCollector.common.kt:113)
        at in.machine_test.arun.viewmodels.ListFragmentViewModel$insert$1.invokeSuspend(ListFragmentViewModel.kt:59)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:42)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:95)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:749)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
        Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@66b95d6, Dispatchers.IO]
```

Below is the code which I have written in LoginFragment.

```
companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun getInstance(): ListFragment = ListFragment()
}
```

Trying to get the instance from ViewModel

```
private fun showToast(message: String) {
   ListFragment.getInstance().requireActivity().runOnUiThread {
      Toast.makeText(mContext, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
   }
}
```

To get the instance, I know there are other ways like passing the instance of this class in viewModel constructor or use a dependency injection.

But I am wondering how to get an instance using this getInstance approach.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error's telling you the problem:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment ListFragment{b13aa81} ...
    not attached to an activity.
```

You're getting this `not attached to an activity` error because you're trying to use this `Fragment` that you've just created to get access to an `Activity`

```
ListFragment.getInstance().requireActivity()
```

And that's not how Android works. Usually when you have access to a `Fragment` it's because *the system provided it*, e.g. by attaching it to an `Activity` or `ViewPager` or something.

The `Fragment` gets created - and it's just a class, with no access to the app `Context` or anything - and then the system *connects it* to the wider app framework by attaching it to another component, which is a hierarchy that is ultimately running in an `Activity` (which is like a view of the app, running in a `Window`).

If you just do `MyFragment()` you're just creating that basic class - it has no connection to an `Activity`, because you didn't give it one. And in the context of your code, a basic function in a *companion object*, *you can't give it one because the function doesn't have access to one*.

---

I'm just explaining this to make it clearer what the limitations are here - I think you're already aware of them, and that's why you're trying to get access to an `Activity` somehow, because currently you don't have access to it. But just creating a `ListFragment` can't give you access you don't already have. There's no magic to it.

You basically have two options for this situation, which comes up a lot! (Especially for `Context`s):

- your code is running in a component that has (or usually has) access to an `Activity`, `Context` etc, like a *running* `Fragment` (i.e. in its lifecycle callbacks like `onCreate`), or it has a parent object it can get access through. Access it that way
- your code doesn't have access, so you need to *provide* the `Context` etc, either as a parameter in a function call, or as a constructor parameter. The thing that calls the function or constructs the object needs to have access to the `Context`, so it can pass it in

That's what I mean about there being no magic, no tricks to gain access to things. Either you have access, or something needs to provide it. To give your `ListFragment` access to an `Activity`, you need access to that `Activity` yourself so you can attach the fragment to it! There's no workaround for that

---

As far as your specific problem goes, you just want to run your `Toast` call on the main thread, right? `Activity#runOnUiThread` is a convenience method for when you have access to an `Activity` - but you can do the same thing like this:

```
// this lets you post runnables to the message queue on the main thread
val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
// now you can run your code on it
handler.post { Toast.makeText(mContext, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }
```

I see you're using coroutines in your stacktrace, so maybe you just want to switch to the `Main` dispatcher instead:

```
withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Depends on what you're doing!

Comment: Understood. Thank you for the explanations, alternate solutions and pointing out the mistakes. Appreciate a lot.

Comment: @ArunSivanandan no worries - it's just a thing you get used to! Generally speaking, you don't need access to an `Activity` unless you're running inside one (so you probably have access to it). And a lot of the time what you really need is a `Context`, so you get used to passing those into your classes and functions as a parameter. It's like a bridge to the environment the app is running in, its resources etc. If you get used to doing that, it becomes a lot easier! Still a few awkward situations to get around, but hey